# Использовать свои теги и свои атрибуты без data-* в html

Tags: html, html5, валидация

Почему плохо использовать свои теги (`<mytag></mytag>`) и свои атрибуты без `data-*` в `html`?

Насчёт тегов, вот так вставляется Яндекс карта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Следовательно, вопрос - почему им можно, а нам нет?

Comment: Аттрибуты там стандартные. А тэги новые, наверное, чтобы стандартные стили не мешались, не знаю.

Comment: Так использование кастомных тэгов это нормально ?

Comment: Браузеры современные их скушают и обработают. Но со стороны стандарта не знаю, а искать лень :) http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

Comment: Использование таких тегов <mytag> в первую очередь невалидно,но с помощью веб компонентов можно сделать  так <my-tag>, обязательно через дефис.

Answer (score 1):

Могут быть кастомные теги это не плохо, бреузеры спокойно их поддерживают, но дефолтные теги разбивают страницу на логические части с теми названиями которые соответсвуют контенту, это упрощает индексацию, роботам более понятна струтура сайта, лучшая семантика. 
data я думаю также семантика, доступ в javascript и в css, как получить доступ без data в псевдо елемент css, наверное не возможно.